# How to return to original scene?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, segue

I navigate from scene A to scene B with a segue and want to return to A by touching a button. Do I have to create a new segue to get back or should I do something else? If I create a new segue, will it be a circular-reference?

Comment: Are you using iOS6 or iOS5? The answer is different.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist  My app have to support ios5 and ios6.

Comment: try [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; in an IBAction

Comment: @MauriceA. Thank you,it works.But I have to do some configure to destination view controller before return back(such as changing button title). How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the way you segue if you are using modal segue style then you have to do this,

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

if push style segue

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Do any one depending on your segue style in the IBAction method of the button you wish to use.

Comment: Thank you,it works.But I have to do some configure to destination view controller before return back(such as changing button title). How should I do?

Comment: ok you can do it with navigationController delegate methods or the best way do it viewWillAppear method of your destination view controller. Accept ans if you are cool!. Hope this helps for navigationController delegate http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html